# Linq query require for a join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am having two below tables. I need to unassigned rights for group 3 and my sql query is like below

select rightname 
    from IB_Right_Master 
    where id 
    not in (select RightID from IB_Group_Rights where GroupID = '3');

```
Table : RightMaster

ID   |   RightName   |  RightGroupName       |
----------------------------------------------
1    |  Test1         |   test1              |
----------------------------------------------
2    |  Test2         |   test2              |
----------------------------------------------
3    |  Test3         |    Test3             |
----------------------------------------------
4    |  Test4         |   Group Test4        |
----------------------------------------------
```

Table : Group Rgihts

```
ID   |   RightID     |      GroupID         |         
----------------------------------------------
1    |    1          |       1              |     
----------------------------------------------
2    |    1          |       2              |  
---------------------------------------------
3    |    2          |       3              | 
---------------------------------------------
4    |    3          |       4              | 
---------------------------------------------
5    |    1          |       3              |  
---------------------------------------------
```

Desired Output : for a group id 3

```
RightID   |   RightName     |            
----------------------------- 
3         |  Page Access    |      
------------------------------ 
4         |  Delete Group   |     
-----------------------------
```

Comment: . . . and what's your question?

Comment: where is inner join in sql query

Comment: @Binary Worrier I need linq query for the above sql query.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude need linq for this query----- select id as "Right ID", rightname from IB_Right_Master where id not in (select RightID from 
IB_Group_Rights where id = '1');

Comment: @ L.B I am looking for linq query for this sql query ---- select id as "Right ID", rightname from IB_Right_Master where id not in (select RightID from IB_Group_Rights where id = '1');

Comment: @vim SQL expressions need formatting, just like any other code. Operators such as `from`, `where`, `join` etc. should start a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
from e in context.IB_Right_Master
where  !(from e2 in context.IB_Group_Rights
     where e2.GroupID == 3
     select e2.RightID).ToList().Contains(e.id)
select e;
```

Comment: I just edited my sql query .I need to check group id.please chk once again thanks

Comment: It is giving all four records of Right Master table.

Comment: @vim now check you this query

Comment: I am just testing the query. initially it is giving exact output.i am just checking with some other combination as well.i will confirm you in few mins